# Library makes my Android APK too big

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, proguard, android-library

I have my own custom library that I use to maintain methods and classes I want to use in multiple projects.  It's not compiled into a .jar file - it's set up as com.android.library and sits in its own folder.

One of my apps is very small - less than 500k.  When I added this library, it ballooned to 1350k.  Even though it's still small, this is a problem for this particular app, which I've committed to being as small as possible.

The src folder for the app itself is 77k.  The src folder for the library project is 112k.  The .dex file of the resulting apk is exactly 1mb.  **How is this possible?**

The library project does reference play-services-vision. However it's not referenced in this app, and I believe that Proguard should be stripping it out.

In the 'Build Variants' window, both the app and the library are set to "release".

My app's build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
       //**CONFIG STUFF**//
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
            versionNameSuffix '.debug'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile project(':farmsoftlibs')
}
```

*Note: the appcompat reference was also in an older version of my app that was 500k, so I know that's not the primary culprit.*

My Library's build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:7.8.0'
}
```

So my questions that I think might solve the puzzle are:

1. How is my apk bigger than my full java & res folders for the app and library combined, especially since I'm using Proguard?
2. Is there something that gradle is pulling in from my library project that is making my apk larger?
3. How can I make sure only the library methods and classes that my app is actually using is loaded into the apk?

Let me know if another file is relevant to answering this question.  Thanks!

Comment: You are using some support libraries. It is normal, and in any case 1M is not too big!

Answer (score 0):

1. `java` file is compiled into `class` file before packing in, which is usually larger than `java` source. I am not sure how you check your library size, but please refer to answer of questions 2
2. `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:7.8.0'`, a dependency like this, can contains more than 1 jar, because of transitive dependencies, i.e. the library you used depends on 1 or more libraries and they can further depends on other libraries as well
3. if you have `minifyEnabled=true`, and you haven't changed `proguard-rules.pro` to `-keep` unnecessary class or methods, it should do the job.

Further information on questions 2, with my test, `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:7.8.0'`, at least added 4 dependencies `play-services-vision`, `play-services-base`, `support-annotations` and `support-v4`.

Moreover, please be reminded that with your config, proguard would only shrink (remove unnecessary classes) in your `Release` build, but not `Debug` build.

Peronsal opnion: actually 1.3MB should be considered very small already

Comment: Interestingly, I can't find proguard-rules.pro  on my computer at all.  Would that cripple Proguard?  Assuming that vision and its 4 dependencies are being included in my app's dex files, is it reasonable to assume they would be stripped out by proguard or am I misunderstanding how it works?

Comment: If you have created your project with Android Studio, you should have it under your `app` folder

Comment: Actually it contains only comments for new project, so you can just create a blank file to put there if it is really missing.

Comment: aha - it just has the default #comments.  I'm trying to understand the implications of your answer though - are you saying that proguard should be stripping out vision and its 4 dependencies or am I expecting too much? How can I know?  I know 1.3mb is still smallish. The app is very simple and tight and part of the promise is there's no bloat or spyware buried inside.

Comment: Sorry to ask this, but just to confirm, are you checking your release or debug apk?

Comment: In the 'Build Variants' window, I've set both the app and the library to "release". I'll add that to the question.

Comment: `are you saying that proguard should be stripping out vision and its 4 dependencies or am I expecting too much?`, yes you are expecting too much, proguard can only remove classes that you is not needed

Comment: you can build your debug apk to check the size to compare

Comment: Just to clarify, by saying that proguard is not going to remove classes in the dependencies, I mean not ALL the classes would be removed, because obviously your library should be using some of the classes from the dependencies.

Comment: So the app is definitely not using the vision api our any of the class in the library that reference the vision api. I just branched the library and deleted those classes and the compile statement and then rebuilt the app. It was 650k. So I think it's odd that Proguard included those dependencies that the app doesn't use

Comment: ic, you should check this https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/android-4.1.2_r2/files/proguard-android.txt this is actually what android default to keep

Comment: It should be caused by `support-v4` in the dependency which contains classes which extends `Activity`, `Services`, `Context`. I am sorry that I never imagined you are actually not using the `vision` library